# How can i update a ListBox from a static class?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

My XAML markup is

```
   <Grid x:Name="gdTest" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="5,0,5,0" >
       <ListBox Width="400" Margin="10" x:Name="lstDemo">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=id}" Margin="20" />
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" Margin="20"/>
                </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
   </Grid>
```

My super class is

```
public class SuperClass
    {
        public Arguments arguments;

        public class Stat
        {
            public int downloadCount;
        }

        public class Files
        {
            public int id;
            public string name;
            public List<Stat> SomeStats;
        }

        public class Arguments
        {
            public List<Files> Files;
        }
    }
```

In the App Class i declared my SuperClass as static. (The App.SuperClass gets filled in intervals of a dispatch timer).

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   public static SuperClass SuperClass = new SuperClass();
}
```

And finally when i bind the list of the static class to the ListBox, nothing is displayed in the emulator.

```
lstDemo.ItemsSource = App.SuperClass.arguments.Files;
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using public fields use [automatic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). 
Use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for ItemsSource binding, so your listbox is notified when add/remove event occurs.

```
public class SuperClass 
{
    public Arguments Args { get; set; }

    public class Stat
    {
        public int DownloadCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class File
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Stat> SomeStats { get; set; }
    }

    public class Arguments 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you been for so long? Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the List to [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Strandard list collection does not do Notification on add/remove as such on UI won't get updated.

```
public class Arguments
{
       public ObservableCollection<Files> Files;
}
```

Also, instead of directly setting ItemsSource this way, better approach would be to use Xaml Binding of ItemsSource with a ViewModel.